# OS development: How to avoid an infinite loop after an exception routine

Tags: exception, assembly, operating-system, x86, interruption

For some months I've been working on a "home-made" operating system.
Currently, it boots and goes into 32-bit protected mode.
I've loaded the interrupt table, but haven't set up the pagination (yet).

Now while writing my exception routines I've noticed that when an instruction throws an exception, the exception routine is executed, but then the CPU jumps back to the instruction which threw the exception! This does not apply to every exception (for example, a div by zero exception will jump back to the instruction AFTER the division instruction), but let's consider the following general protection exception:

```
MOV EAX, 0x8
MOV CS, EAX
```

My routine is simple: it calls a function that displays a red error message.

The result: MOV CS, EAX fails -> My error message is displayed -> CPU jumps back to MOV CS -> infinite loop spamming the error message.

I've talked about this issue with a teacher in operating systems and unix security.
He told me he knows Linux has a way around it, but he doesn't know which one.

The naive solution would be to parse the throwing instruction from within the routine, in order to get the length of that instruction.
That solution is pretty complex, and I feel a bit uncomfortable adding a call to a relatively heavy function in every affected exception routine...

Therefore, I was wondering if the is another way around the problem. Maybe there's a "magic" register that contains a bit that can change this behaviour?

--

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion/information.

--

**EDIT**: It seems many people wonder why I want to skip over the problematic instruction and resume normal execution.

I have two reasons for this:

1. First of all, killing a process would be a possible solution, but not a clean one. That's not how it's done in Linux, for example, where (AFAIK) the kernel sends a signal (I think SIGSEGV) but does not immediately break execution. It makes sense, since the application can block or ignore the signal and resume its own execution. It's a very elegant way to tell the application it did something wrong IMO.
2. Another reason: what if the kernel itself performs an illegal operation? Could be due to a bug, but could also be due to a kernel extension. As I've stated in a comment: what should I do in that case? Shall I just kill the kernel and display a nice blue screen with a smiley?

That's why I would like to be able to jump over the instruction. "Guessing" the instruction size is obviously not an option, and parsing the instruction seems fairly complex (not that I mind implementing such a routine, but I need to be sure there is no better way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different exceptions have different causes. Some exceptions are normal, and the exception only tells the kernel what it needs to do before allowing the software to continue running. Examples of this include a page fault telling the kernel it needs to load data from swap space, an undefined instruction exception telling the kernel it needs to emulate an instruction that the CPU doesn't support, or a debug/breakpoint exception telling the kernel it needs to notify a debugger. For these it's normal for the kernel to fix things up and silently continue.

Some exceptions indicate abnormal conditions (e.g. that the software crashed). The only sane way of handling these types of exceptions is to stop running the software. You may save information (e.g. core dump) or display information (e.g. "blue screen of death") to help with debugging, but in the end the software stops (either the process is terminated, or the kernel goes into a "do nothing until user resets computer" state).

Ignoring abnormal conditions just makes it harder for people to figure out what went wrong. For example, imagine instructions to go to the toilet:

- enter bathroom
- remove pants
- sit
- start generating output

Now imagine that step 2 fails because you're wearing shorts (a "can't find pants" exception). Do you want to stop at that point (with a nice easy to understand error message or something), or ignore that step and attempt to figure out what went wrong later on, after all the useful diagnostic information has gone?

Comment: I understand your point. I know it wouldn't make sense to continue executing a process which generated a segment fault, but I just *want* to do it, mainly out of curiosity.

From what I've understood so far, it's not possible to do it in an easy way (no magic register defining the interrupt behaviour, for example).

Comment: If you actually do want to do it; then you have to implement a decoder to determine the length of the instruction from raw bytes in RAM. This would be a large amount of work for 80x86 (variable length instructions, prefixes, etc). Once you've got it "working" it still won't work in some cases. For example, imagine a page fault caused by "page not present" - you can't attempt to decode bytes that don't exist.

Comment: I know it would be a large amount of work. Haven't thought of the page faults, but that's not such a big issue (well at least, not yet, in my case).

Comment: `PantsNotFoundException`. I'd like to see that somewhere in real code someday.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to skip the instruction that caused the exception (e.g. `mov cs, eax`) and continue executing the program at the next instruction.

Why would you want to do this? Normally, shouldn't the rest of the program depend on the effects of that instruction being successfully executed?

Generally speaking, there are three approaches to exception handling:

- Treat the exception as an unrepairable condition and kill the process. For example, division by zero is usually handled this way.
- Repair the environment and then execute the instruction again. For example, page faults are sometimes handled this way.
- Emulate the instruction using software and skip over it in the instruction stream. For example, complicated arithmetic instructions are sometimes handled this way.

Comment: If the instruction appeared in a process, then indeed, killing the process would be the easiest solution. However, what if the instruction appears right in the kernel? Not necessarily the base kernel code, could also be a kernel extension... I can't just kill the kernel! (I'm not trying to reinvent windows) ;) I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with the 3rd point regarding software emulation, but it seems even more complicated than simply decoding the instruction!

Comment: The third point about emulation is for a situation like the CPU doesn't support floating-point, but you want to emulate those instructions in software.

Comment: Could you answer these questions? "Why would you want to do this? Normally, shouldn't the rest of the program depend on the effects of that instruction being successfully executed?"

Comment: I edited my original post, where I hope I answered to your questions.

Comment: I understand you're concerned about kernel extensions that might run faulty code. If that's the case, have you considered spawning separate processes to run such code so that you can kill offending kernel processes without bringing down the main kernel?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the characteristic of the General Protection Exception. The Intel System Programming Guide clearly states that (6.15 Exception and Interrupt Reference / Interrupt 13 - General Protection Exception (#GP)) :

```
Saved Instruction Pointer
The saved contents of CS and EIP registers point to the instruction that generated the
exception.
```

Therefore, you need to write an exception handler that will skip over that instruction (which would be kind of weird), or just simply kill the offending process with "General Protection Exception at `$SAVED_EIP`" or a similar message.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a few situations in which one would want to respond to a GPF by parsing the failed instruction, emulating its operation, and then returning to the instruction after.  The normal pattern would be to set things up so that the instruction, if retried, would succeed, but one might e.g. have some code that expects to access some hardware at addresses 0x000A0000-0x000AFFFF and wish to run it on a machine that lacks such hardware.  In such a situation, one might not want to ever bank in "real" memory in that space, since every single access must be trapped and dealt with separately.  I'm not sure whether there's any way to handle that without having to decode whatever instruction was trying to access that memory, although I do know that some virtual-PC programs seem to manage it pretty well.

Otherwise, I would suggest that you should have for each thread a jump vector which should be used when the system encounters a GPF.  Normally that vector should point to a thread-exit routine, but code which was about to do something "suspicious" with pointers could set it to an error handler that was suitable for that code (the code should unset the vector when laving the region where the error handler would have been appropriate).

I can imagine situations where one might want to emulate an instruction without executing it, and cases where one might want to transfer control to an error-handler routine, but I can't imagine any where one would want to simply skip over an instruction that would have caused a GPF.